# Wrapped C library in Python, but returned array is unchanged

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

This is my first attempt at using Ctypes. I have a C dll which does simple buffer manipulation of adding 1 to its contents.

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int AddBuffer(unsigned char* data, unsigned char len)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + data[i];
            data[i] = data[i] + 1;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

And in my python code I have

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,8,4,6,9]
myfunc = test_dll.AddBuffer
myfunc.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8),ctypes.c_uint8)
data_array = ctypes.c_uint8 * len(data)
result = myfunc(data_array(*data),ctypes.c_uint8(len(data)))
print result
for i in range (0,len(data)):
     print  data[i]
```

The result I get is 42 but the contents of data remain unchanged. I have looked but still cannot find the reason.

Comment: Looks like you're modifying the result of `data_array(*data)` rather than actually modifying `data` itself. Do the contents of `data_array` change?

Comment: @spiffman that's the problem, but `data_array` is a type, not an instance of that type as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

> ```
> data_array = ctypes.c_uint8 * len(data)
> result = myfunc(data_array(*data),ctypes.c_uint8(len(data)))
> ```

Creates an anonymous copy of `data`, in an instance of a ctypes array type called `data_array`.

When you pass the `data_array` instance you anonymously create to your function that's what is getting modified, the new copy.

Instead you need:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,8,4,6,9]
myfunc = test_dll.AddBuffer
myfunc.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint8),ctypes.c_uint8)
data_array = ctypes.c_uint8 * len(data)
arg = data_array(*data)
result = myfunc(arg,ctypes.sizeof(arg))
print result
for i in range (0,len(arg)):
     print  arg[i]
```

Which prints out the same array passed in to the function and makes sure the array you pass in is named instead of anonymous.

Comment: Hi thanks that worked, my understanding here is that data_array is some allocated memory with exactly 9 bytes which is filled up with the contents of data. But when I tried print data_array, i found that its not iterable. So here what is difference between arg and data_array here

Comment: `data_array` is a python representation of the type `uint8[9]`. It's the same as the difference between a class and an instance of a class in regular python without ctypes. `arg` is an instance of that type that you copy `data` into in my example